# I can't get Seaborn to import

Tags: python, import, seaborn

I'm trying to add Seaborn to my Anaconda3 python installation, and get multiple failure codes.  It successfully installed using conda ... but won't import.  After multiple installs/deletion/reinstalls of scipy, numpy, and seaborn, I get the following error message.  I'm running Python 3.9.12, numpy 1.22.0 (downgraded from 1.23 due to prev error message stating had to be < 1.23 for Seaborn to install -- on a Windows 10.   Any suggestions would be appreciated.

I can't post an image yet, so here's a summary of the error message with the failure points

code:
import Seaborn as sns

ImportError
...

1. import seaborn as sns
2. from .rcmod import * # noqa:F401, F403
3. from .import palettes
4. from . import _arpack

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _arpack: The specified procedure could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

It is not issue of seaborn. First of all uninstall numpy using this command

```
pip uninstall -y numpy
```

Then uninstall setuptools with this command

```
pip uninstall -y setuptools
```

Now, reinstall setuptools with this command

```
pip install setuptools
```

Then, You can reinstall numpy with this command

```
pip install numpy
```

Now, Your error must be solved.

Comment: If it doesn't help try: $>conda remove --force numpy, scipy and $> pip install numpy
$> pip install scipy

Comment: thanks for your response Mahammad ... I don't get the Seaborn error now, but I now get attribute errors on pandas ... module pandas has no attribute Timestamp, and moduel pandas has no attribute 'tslib'